# Nesting a for comprehension inside a yield

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I am getting a compile error with this code. I have stripped it down to simplify it as much as possible. I am using cats `EitherT` monad transformer here.

```scala
  def foo(
    id : String
  ): EitherT[Future, Err, Either[A, B]] =
    for {
      a <- f1(id)
    } yield {
      if (a > 2)
        Left(A("Got an a"))
      else {
        for {
          b <- f2() // THIS IS THE PROBLEM
        } yield (Right(B("Got a B"))
      }
    }
```

The compiler is complaining about f2(). It has a return type of `EitherT[Future,Err,C]`. The complier error I am getting is:

```
[error]  found   : cats.data.EitherT[Future,Err,scala.util.Right[Nothing,B]]
[error]  required: Either[A,B]
[error]           b <- f2()
```

I am not sure why it is complaining about this. I want to do the "if" check as a guard on the call to `f2()` but I cannot as `EitherT` does not have a withFilter method. Is there  a better way to do this? Basic logic is, make call to `f1()`. If the value of `a > 2` do not call f2 but if it is not then call f2.

Comment: Nested type of `EitherT[Future, Err, Either[A,B]]` is a little bit weird, what are you trying to achieve? Are you sure you need separate error types `A` and `Err`? Can you show signatures of `f1` and `f2`?

Comment: f1 return type is EitherT[Future, Err, Long]. f2 is in the post -> EitherT[Future, Err, C]

Comment: @KrzysztofAtłasik I mention in last paragraph what I want to achieve. If return value from f1 is grate than 2 I do not want to call f2. But if return value is less than 2 then I want to call f2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try single `flatMap` instead of nested for-comprehensions like so

```
case class A(v: String)
case class B(v: String)
case class C(v: String)

def f1(id: String): EitherT[Future, Err, Long] = EitherT.rightT(42)
def f2(): EitherT[Future, Err, C] = EitherT.rightT(C("cc"))

def foo(id : String): EitherT[Future, Err, Either[A, B]] =
  f1(id).flatMap { a =>
    if (a > 2)
      EitherT.rightT(Left(A("Got an A")))
    else
      f2().map(b => Right(B("Got a B")))
  }

foo("123").value.andThen(v => println(v))
```

which outputs

```
Success(Right(Left(A(Got an A))))
```

however I second Krzysztof's suggestion that `EitherT[Future, Err, Either[A, B]]` models seems a bit unusual.